# Ubuntu 16.04 no sound through hdmi

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound, hdmi, amd-graphics

I'm  using Ubuntu 16.04 on a HP Pavillion dv6 which I bought in 2012. Everything works fine, but I'm unable to get any sound over HDMI to my TV.

```
$ uname -a
Linux stone 4.8.0-32-lowlatency #34~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 13 18:13:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci | grep Audio
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300 Series] (rev ff)

$ lspci | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470] (rev ff)

$ aplay -l
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
Karte 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], Gerät 0: 92HD81B1X5 Analog [92HD81B1X5 Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

I tried several things I found on the Internet:

- change `etc/default/grub` to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modeprobe radeon.modeset=1 radeon.audio=1"
  ```
- reinstall pavucontrol, alsamixer
- kernel update to 4.8.0

What else can I do?

Comment: Do you get sound output from your laptop while hdmi is connected?

Comment: Yes. I have speakers connected to the jack plug for sound.

Comment: Make sure you changed your sound output from _(Unity) Settings -> Sound -> Output_ to your HDMI device and check again.

Comment: Ther is no HDMI device to select, even if the TV is connected over HDMI.

Comment: Are you using open _(default)_ or closed _(AMD manually installed)_ drivers? I used a HP laptop from same series (also same grpahic card i think, HD5450 ) and a Acer with HD5650 without problems using open source driver.

Comment: I'm using default radeon driver. I've tried for weeks now to get it work with no succes. But today it worked. I just connected HDMI cable and looked for something to select and there was a HDMI sound device. No idea what was different now. So thanks for your answers!

Comment: Glad to see it worked. Now I think I should have written an answer :)